# Memory leak in the Win64 Delphi RTL during thread shutdown?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-xe2, win64

For a long time I’ve noticed that the Win64 version of my server application leak memory. While the Win32 version works fine with a relatively stable memory footprint, the memory used by the 64 bit version increases regularly – maybe 20Mb/day, without any apparent reason (Needless to say, FastMM4 did not report any memory leak for both of them). The source code is identical between the 32bit and the 64bit version. The application is built around the Indy TIdTCPServer component, it is a highly multithreaded server connected to a database that processes commands sent by other clients made with Delphi XE2.

I spend a lot of time reviewing my own code and trying to understand why the 64 bit version leaked so much memory. I ended up by using MS tools designed to track memory leaks like DebugDiag and XPerf and it seems there is a fundamental flaw in the Delphi 64bit RTL that causes some bytes to be leaked each time a thread has detached from a DLL. This issue is particularly critical for highly multithreaded applications that must run 24/7 without being restarted.

I reproduced the problem with a very basic project that is composed by an host application and a library, both built with XE2. The DLL is statically linked with the host app. The host app creates threads that just call the dummy exported procedure and exit:

Here is the source code of the library:

```
library FooBarDLL;

uses
  Windows,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

{$R *.res}

function FooBarProc(): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  Result := True; //Do nothing.
end;

exports
  FooBarProc;
```

The host application uses a timer to create a thread that just call the exported procedure:

```
  TFooThread = class (TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

...

function FooBarProc(): Boolean; stdcall; external 'FooBarDll.dll';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure THostAppForm.TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TFooThread.Create() do
    Start;
end;

{ TFooThread }

constructor TFooThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TFooThread.Execute;
begin
  /// Call the exported procedure.
  FooBarProc();
end;
```

Here is some screenshots that show the leak using VMMap (look at the red line named "Heap"). The following screenshots were taken within a 30 minutes interval.

The 32 bit binary shows an increase of 16 bytes, which is totally acceptable:

[image: Memory usage for the 32 bit version]

The 64 bit binary shows an increase of 12476 bytes (from 820K to 13296K), which is more problematic:

[image: Memory usage for the 64 bit version]

The constant increase of heap memory is also confirmed by XPerf:

[XPerf usage](https://web.archive.org/web/20120518230757/http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg825/scaled.php?server=825&filename=soxperf.png&res=landing)

Using DebugDiag I was able to see the code path that was allocating the leaked memory:

```
LeakTrack+13529
<my dll>!Sysinit::AllocTlsBuffer+13
<my dll>!Sysinit::InitThreadTLS+2b
<my dll>!Sysinit::::GetTls+22
<my dll>!System::AllocateRaiseFrame+e
<my dll>!System::DelphiExceptionHandler+342
ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+d
ntdll!RtlDispatchException+45a
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+2e
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+39
<my dll>!System::::RaiseAtExcept+106
<my dll>!System::::RaiseExcept+1c
<my dll>!System::ExitDll+3e
<my dll>!System::::Halt0+54
<my dll>!System::::StartLib+123
<my dll>!Sysinit::::InitLib+92
<my dll>!Smart::initialization+38
ntdll!LdrShutdownThread+155
ntdll!RtlExitUserThread+38
<my application>!System::EndThread+20
<my application>!System::Classes::ThreadProc+9a
<my application>!SystemThreadWrapper+36
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+d
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d
```

Remy Lebeau [helped me on the Embarcadero forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=456502&tstart=0) to understand what was happening:

> The second leak looks more like a definite bug.  During thread
>   shutdown,  StartLib() is being called, which calls ExitThreadTLS() to
>   free the calling  thread's TLS memory block, then calls Halt0() to
>   call ExitDll() to raise  an exception that is caught by
>   DelphiExceptionHandler() to call AllocateRaiseFrame(),  which
>   indirectly calls GetTls() and thus InitThreadTLS() when it accesses  a
>   threadvar variable named ExceptionObjectCount.  That re-allocates the
>   TLS  memory block of the calling thread that is still in the process
>   of being  shut down.  So either StartLib() should not be calling
>   Halt0() during DLL_THREAD_DETACH,  or DelphiExceptionHandler should
>   not be calling AllocateRaiseFrame() when  it detects a
>   _TExitDllException being raised.

It seems clear for me that there is an major flaw in the Win64 way to handle threads shutdown. A such behavior prohibits the development of any multithreaded server application that must run 27/7 under Win64.

So:

1. What do you think of my conclusions?
2. Do any of you have a workaround for this issue?

[QC Report 105559](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220162905/http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=105559)

Comment: "Do any of you have a workaround for this issue" I would use the 32bit app until the next <too-strong>stable</too-strong> release of delphi with 64bit compiler comes along...

Comment: If I were you I would cut this down to a sample of bare minimum size, that exhibits the leak, and simply submit it to QC.

Comment: @DorinDuminica: that would be Delphi XE4 then ;)

Comment: @whosrdaddy same feeling here, I hope we're wrong tho ):

Comment: Funny enough, it seems that a same kind of bug has already been reported in 2009 (I suppose that it was in the Win32 RTL) :
http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.rtl/200903/0903231085.html
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=72439
Nevertheless it seems it has been fixed now since the Win32 version of my test project does not leak memory.

Comment: I made some updates to the QC report and then marked it for Sysop attention so it can get promoted to Embarcdero's internal tracker.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : Many thanks, I also attached my source code, if they really need it...

Comment: Upvote for the effort expended in compiling this question.

Comment: @Glorfindel I see you've updated the links less than 6 months ago: but I wonder why you left one image on imageshack, and why the link to free.fr is now dead after you've edited it.

Comment: @Cœur it's an automated script, and it only does the things I've told it to do. I guess the remaining imageshack.us link wasn't detected as an image, and I'm not sure about the free.fr one. It could have been working last August.

Comment: @Glorfindel OK, it's using desmond.imageshack.us instead of the more classic imgXX.imageshack.us, so that could explain why the script didn't got it. And as for the link to free.fr, I guess you've probably just applied the redirect while the actual file was already unavailable at that time.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple work around is to re-use the thread and not create and destroy them. Threads are pretty expensive, you'll probably get a perf boost too... Kudos on the debugging though...

Comment: Yes, that was my very first idea. In my specific case I could certainly use a thread pool. But that won't prevent third-party code included in my project to schedule new threads that will also leak...

Comment: Thats true, but if you have the source for your third-party stuff you can adapt it to use your thread pool, if you don't there isn't anything you'll be able to do about it anyway...
If you absolutely have to run external leaky dlls, you should do it in a separate process that you can re-start every now and then, but that's not always possible.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the exception memoryleak trap, you could try to put an try/except around the FoobarProc. Maybe not for a definitive solution, but to see why the axception is raised in the first place.

I usually have something like this:

```
try
  FooBarProc()
except
  if IsFatalException(ExceptObject) then // checks for system exceptions like AV, invalidop etc
    OutputDebugstring(PChar(ExceptionToString(ExceptObject))) // or some other way of logging
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Delphi 10.2.3 and the problem described seems to still exist, at least under the following circumstances.

```
// Remark: My TFooThread is created within the 64 Bit DLL:

procedure TFooThread.Execute;
begin
 while not terminated do
  try
   ReadBlockingFromIndySocket();
   ProcessData();
  except on E:Exception do
   begin
    LogTheException(E.Message);
    // Leave loop and thread
    Abort;
   end
  end;
end;
```

This leaks memory whenever the loop/thread is left. MadExcept leak report shows that an exception object is not destroyed, in my case mostly an EIdConnClosedGracefully when the connection was closed remotely. The problem was found to be the Abort statement to leave the loop and thus the thread. Indications in the leak report seem to proof the observations of @RemyLebeau. Running the exact same code in the main program instead of the 64 Bit DLL does not leak any memory.

Solution: Exchange the Abort statement with Exit.

Conclusion: A thread execution function in a 64 Bit DLL must not be left with an exception (Abort is an exception as well), or else the exception causes a memory leak.

At least this worked for me.